# Does the Mobius Inversion Theorem hold when sum function is over multiples instead of divisors

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function, mobius-function

Does the Mobius Inversion Theorem hold when the sum function is over multiples instead of divisors.

Formally, are the following two expressions equivalent:

$$
f(n) = \sum_{k:n|k}h(k) * \mu\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$

and

$$
h(n) = \sum_{k:n|k}f(k)
$$

---

I encountered this while solving a problem which had $h$ as:

$$
h(k) = \left\lfloor\frac{\alpha}{k}\right\rfloor
\left\lfloor\frac{\beta}{k}\right\rfloor
$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants

Specifically in that problem I had the following expression:
$$
F(g) = \sum_{k:g|k}\mu\left(\frac{k}{g}\right)h(k)\tag{1}
$$

Then I assumed that Mobius Inversion Theorem holds when sum function is over multiples, to get:

$$
h(g) = \sum_{k:g|k}F(k)
$$

which gives me:

$$
F(g) = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{g}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{m}{g}\right\rfloor - \sum_{k:g|k, k \neq g}F(k)\tag{2}
$$

I wrote [this](http://ideone.com/5BmeNy) code(C++) to check whether $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent, and it seems that they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that all functions considered are decaying fast enough (we will be a bit more explicit with what "fast enough" is below) that we need not worry about convergence and the validity of reordering the sums. For such functions, let's define

$$S(f) \colon n \mapsto \sum_{k : n\mid k} f(k) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} f(m\cdot n)$$

and

$$M(f) \colon n \mapsto \sum_{k : n\mid k} \mu\biggl(\frac{k}{n}\biggr) f(k) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \mu(m) f(m\cdot n).$$

Then we have indeed $M(S(f)) = f = S(M(f))$. The key is, as for the usual Möbius inversion, that

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) = \begin{cases} 1 &, n = 1 \\ 0 &, n > 1. \end{cases}$$

With that, we calculate

\begin{align}
M(S(f))(n) &= \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} S(f)(mn) \\
&= \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mu(k)f(kmn) \\
&= \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \Biggl(\sum_{k \mid r} \mu(k)\Biggr) f(rn) \\
&= f(n)
\end{align}

and similarly

\begin{align}
S(M(f))(n) &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mu(k)M(f)(kn) \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \mu(k)f(kmn) \\
&= \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \Biggl(\sum_{k \mid r} \mu(k)\Biggr) f(rn) \\
&= f(n).
\end{align}

In your example, we have $h(k) = 0$ for $k > c := \min\: \{\lvert\alpha\rvert,\, \lvert\beta\rvert\}$, and hence also $F(k) = 0$ for $k > c$, so we are effectively dealing with finite sums and no convergence problems arise. In general, the reordering is certainly legitimate if

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \lvert \mu(k) f(kmn)\rvert = \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \Biggl(\sum_{k \mid r} \lvert \mu(k)\rvert\Biggr) \lvert f(rn)\rvert < +\infty$$

for every $n$, and that is the case if

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \tau(n)\lvert f(n)\rvert < +\infty,$$

where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

We note that essentially the same computation shows that - under suitable conditions - the generalised Möbius inversion formula

$$h(x) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} f\bigl(x\cdot c(m)\bigr) \iff f(x) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \mu(m) h\bigl(x \cdot c(m)\bigr)$$

holds for every non-constant completely multiplicative function $c$. The case $c(m) = \dfrac{1}{m}$ is [famous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations).