# Alternative second Mobius Inversion Formula.

Tags: number-theory, mobius-inversion

I've seen in some places an alternative version of the Mobius Inversion Formula. Instead of the usual:
$$ F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} G(x/n) \iff G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n) F(x/n)$$

I've seen:
$$F(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} G(nx) \iff G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n) F(nx)$$
What I'm wondering is how to prove this second identity and what must these functions $F$ and $G$ fulfill.

Comment: [It's essentially the same computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965342/does-the-mobius-inversion-theorem-hold-when-sum-function-is-over-multiples-inste), also for more general cases. What one needs is fast enough decay of $F$ and $G$ so that rearranging the sums is legitimate.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: To prove it you need absolute convergence and $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) = 1_{n = 1}$